# Docker quickstart - Error ingesting history archive: ledger does not exists

Tags: horizon, testnet, history, docker

I'm trying to run the quickstart docker tutorial but I am getting a `503 still ingesting` when access the `accounts/ACCOUNT_ID` on my `localhost:8000` (horizon).

Looking over my horizon logs I keep receiving this error:

```
time="2021-01-30T05:21:22.717Z" level=error msg="Error in ingestion state machine" current_state="buildFromCheckpoint(checkpointLedger=1546751)" error="Error ingesting history archive: Error while checking for supported protocol version: cannot check if protocol version supported: ledger does not exist" next_state=start pid=375 service=ingest
```

Has someone already see this?

I get this running:

```
docker run --rm -it -p "8000:8000" -p "11626:11626" -p "11625:11625" -p"8002:5432" -v $HOME/stellar:/opt/stellar --name stellar stellar/quickstart --testnet
```

and then checking on logs `tail -f var/logs/supervisor/*`

Comment: Any luck on this problem ? My guess is that the errors are about the new ledgers not being able to be ingested while horizon is still catching up from the disk archive. And I'm waiting to see if that goes off after some time.

Comment: It looks related to this issue on Github https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon/issues/175